# Customer Journey analysis in Google Analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-4

In GA4 dashboard, I'd like to see how customers **move** across the **page types** of my e-commerce.

Ideally I'd like to achieve something like the Journey analysis from Contentsquare, even in the standard Path format of GA.

I already created **Content groups** based on the page type (Product page, Listing page, Cart, etc.) but it seems that I can't use them in **Path explorations**.

Contentsquare Journey Analysis:

[image: Journey Analysis]

Answer (score 0):

This is a good blog post to bookmark: [https://www.orbitmedia.com/blog/user-flow-google-analytics/]. I don't think you'll be able to create and use just one (1) path exploration report AND include each of the content group, which you alluded to in your post. But if you're willing to duplicate the report in a new tab in the Explorer (not a new browser tab), you can apply a filter for the different Content Groups...then it should be pretty painless but you'd have a bunch of reports to look through.

Another way to go about achieving that type of report in GA4 is with a Custom Funnel Exploration instead of the path exploration - only because the pages in your screenshot essentially make up the ecommerce funnel + product/category pages. The funnel report will give you a little more leeway and ability to customize the report than the path exploration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Unfortunately the Path exploration will return all the pages instead of grouping them, while the Funnel exploration is probably more useful if you already know where customers should go. I already setup a funnel for the final part of the funnel (cart to checkout) but I'd like to see on what page type customers are landing and where they go from there, following the most common paths.
Too bad that GA doesn't provide this useful view.